# "static functions with block scope are illegal" error depending on initialisation style?

Tags: c++, static, scope, initialization

I have a class `Library` containing a struct `Transaction`, and the struct has a member variable of type `Patron`.

```cpp
class Patron {
public:
    Patron() { }
};

class Library {
public:
    struct Transaction {
        Patron p;
        Transaction(Patron pp) :p(pp) { }
        Transaction();
    };
};
```

For the default constructor of `Transaction`, I have a function `default_transaction()` returning a const reference to a static object as recommended by Stroustrup in "Programming – Principles and Practices using C++" (p. 324); reasoning: avoid building default value into constructor code, avoid global variable and associated initialisation problems.

```cpp
const Library::Transaction& default_transaction()
{
    static Library::Transaction tt = Library::Transaction(Patron());
    return tt;
}

Library::Transaction::Transaction()
    :p(default_transaction().p) { }

int main()
{
    Library::Transaction t;
}
```

If I change this line

```cpp
static Library::Transaction tt = Library::Transaction(Patron());
```

to

```cpp
static Library::Transaction tt(Patron());
```

i.e., from "explicit" initialisation style to "colloquial", I get an error: "static functions with block scope are illegal".

Why is that? Aren't the two equivalent? And what does the error mean exactly?

Comment: Look up the Most Vexing Parse.

Comment: Thanks! So `tt((Patron()))` would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static Library::Transaction tt(Patron());
```

This is parsed as the declaration of a `static` (storage, not static member) function named `tt` that returns a `Library::Transaction` and takes a *unnamed* function as single argument. The argument function takes no values and returns a `Patron`.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason you can get this error is that the parser literally thinks that you are trying to write a function inside of a function. In my case, because I had missed a closing curly brace. In this case, your error is likely to be followed by another one, saying that local function definitions are illegal.

```
c:\users\roman\code\handmade\code\win32_handmade.cpp(339): error C2267: 'MainWindowCallback': static functions with block scope are illegal
c:\users\roman\code\handmade\code\win32_handmade.cpp(339): error C2601: 'MainWindowCallback': local function definitions are illegal
```